# Pandas - Does row fall below a row with a column value and same id

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I am new to Pandas. I have a Pandas data frame like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], 'val1': [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]})
```

I want to add a column `val2`, that indicates whether an row falls below another row having the same `id` as itself where `val1 == 1`.

The result would be a data frame like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], 'val1': [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], 'val2': [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]})
```

My first thought was to use an apply statement, but these only go by row. And from my experience for loops are never the answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The result should have val1 -> val2 :)

Comment: @Roelant what do you mean by this? Can you elaborate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's try `shift` + `cumsum` inside a `groupby`.

```
df['val2'] = df.groupby('id').val1.apply(
    lambda x: x.shift().cumsum()
).ge(1).astype(int)
```

Or, in an attempt to avoid the `lambda`,

```
df['val2'] = (    
   df.groupby('id')
     .val1.shift()
     .groupby(df.id)
     .cumsum()
     .ge(1)
     .astype(int)
)
```

```
df
   id  val1  val2
0   1     0     0
1   1     1     0
2   1     0     1
3   2     0     0
4   2     1     0
5   2     0     1
6   2     0     1
```

Comment: Hey Coldspeed! This is exactly what I am looking for, thank you! Could you help me with a special scenario (its too similar for me to create a separate question)? What if we were to add another column, and want to test if the row falls below a row where val1 == 1 or another column, say val3, ==1 as well?

Comment: @ChrisC Something like: `df['temp'] = df['val1'] + df['val3']` and then `df['val_new'] = df.groupby('id').temp.apply(
    lambda x: x.shift().cumsum()
).ge(1).astype(int)`

Answer (score 1):

Using `groupby` + `transform`. Similar to coldspeed's but using `bool` conversion for non-zero `cumsum` values.

```
df['val2'] = df.groupby('id')['val1'].transform(lambda x: x.cumsum().shift())\
                                     .fillna(0).astype(bool).astype(int)

print(df)

   id  val1  val2
0   1     0     0
1   1     1     0
2   1     0     1
3   2     0     0
4   2     1     0
5   2     0     1
6   2     0     1
```

Comment: Thank you! It just occurred to me that a group_by might be necessary